# is '@client command' or '@client event' with if statements more efficient (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

Just a quick question which I cannot find the answer too.

which piece of code is more efficient/faster

this:

```
@client.event
async def message(message):
   if message.content == 'x':
      await message.channel.send('y')
```

or this:

```
@client.command()
async def x(ctx):
   await ctx.send('y')
```

syntax might be a little off for the client.command() part, I have only used client.event method so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering, it's important to understand, `on_message` is the base of `commands` extension.

What it does is

```py
commands = {} # example dictionary

@bot.command() # this registers the function in the command dictionary
async def test(ctx: commands.Context):
   # some code here

# after this line is executed, your commands dictionary would look somethig like
# commands = {'test': test} (here, test is coroutine function you made)
```

`on_message` looks for a message.content, if it starts with the prefix, it gets the message without the prefix, then checks if the command called is in the dictionary, if yes, then call the command on that part with the arguments provided. If not, raise `commands.CommandsNotFound`

The above `on_message` I spoke about is the default `on_message` event bound to the bot. This is also a reason why `commands` extension doesn't work if one overrides the `on_message` **event**

Now with that out of the way, python dictionaries are implemented as hash tables. If the amount of if else staement is less then yes, they might be equally performative but in the longer run, dictionary lookup will prevail. Thus, I would say the commands extesnion is better to use.

In addition to the long run benefit, commands extension offers a much better way to manage your code.

```py
if x == "test":
   s = 1
   y = 1
   j = 1
   print(s, y, z)
elif x == "test2":
   s = 2
   y = 2
   j = 2
   print(s, y, z)
elif x == "test3":
   s = 3
   y = 3
   j = 3
   print(s, y, z)
elif x == "test4":
   s = 4
   y = 4
   j = 4
   print(s, y, z)
elif x == "test5":
   s = 5
   y = 5
   j = 5
   print(s, y, z)
```

is certainly not appealing comapred to

```py
def test1():
   s = 1
   y = 1
   j = 1
   print(s, y, z)

def test2():
   s = 2
   y = 2
   j = 2
   print(s, y, z)

def test3():
   s = 3
   y = 3
   j = 3
   print(s, y, z)

def test4():
   s = 4
   y = 4
   j = 4
   print(s, y, z)

def test5():
   s = 5
   y = 5
   j = 5
   print(s, y, z)
```

And it's also much easier to navigate and maintain your code with the command extension!

So, there is no reason for anyone to use `if else` in `on_message` to create commands when given a superior choice, i.e `commands` extesnion

Comment: Been a bit slow to respond but thanks for the info, very comprehensive!